# MySQL 5.7 Stored Procedure syntax error, via phpadmin and Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin, syntax-error

I'm new to stored procedures in MySQL 5.7 and to the helpful pop-up editor.  I have a query that works when put into a regular SQL edit box, but fails when I try to make a stored procedure out of it.  I suspect the `@rank:=@rank+1` is the problem, but of course MySQL is not much help in narrowing it down.

The point is simply to sort some rows by a field (`ccstr`) and then to select item #N where N is an Input parameter.

This works as direct SQL, replacing N with a value, say 3

```
SET @rank:=0;
SELECT ccstr FROM
( SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, ccstr 
  FROM cards
  ORDER BY ccstr ASC)  as B
WHERE B.rank = N;
```

I've tried using the pop-up editor, and every kind of mix and match I can think of such as the following, but all fail:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE readnth
(IN NDX INT)
DECLARE @rank INT;
SET @rank := 0;
SELECT ccstr FROM
(select @rank:=@rank +1 as rank, ccstr from cards
 order by ccstr ASC)
as b where b.rank=ndx;
end //
delimiter ;
```

Any help as to what the generic problem is here would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I don't think you need to declare variables that begin with `@`

Comment: it's the generic "you have a syntax error" unhelpful error.

Comment: When I tried it, the error said it was at `@rank INT`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line:

```
DECLARE @rank INT;
```

Variables beginning with `@` can't be declared.

Another way to code this is with a prepared statement:

```
PREPARE stmt FROM CONCAT('SELECT ccstr FROM cards ORDER by ccstr LIMIT ', (ndx+1), ', 1');
EXECUTE stmt;
```

You have to use a prepared statement because the parameters to `LIMIT` have to be constants, not expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand all the newbie mistakes I was making before. However, by trial and error, the following code does what I needed done. This was generated by MySQL 5.7's processing of a much simpler statement and tweaking it, with MySQL defining the deterministic, contains SQL, security Definer optins, and I put the procedure name in backquotes,and I declared a non-temporary variable.

```
DROP PROCEDURE `thirdguy`; 
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `thirdguy`(IN `param` INT)
 NOT DETERMINISTIC 
CONTAINS SQL
 SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
BEGIN 
declare NNN int default 0; 
set NNN:=param-1; 
SELECT * FROM `cards` order by ccstr ASC 
limit 1 offset NNN ; 
END
```

COMMENT -- regardless, the code shows as WRONG in the pop-up editor, yet it compiles correctly.

Comment: I also removed spaces in the "NNN:=param-1" statement, and maybe that mattered.

Comment: Did this work? If not, it shouldn't be posted as an answer. I don't think you're allowed to use variables in the `LIMIT` clause, that's why I showed a prepared statement in my answer.